# How to retrieve multiple named output parameters in MS ODBC stored procedure call

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to call a stored procedure which has two output arguments, and get the output programmatically in a C++ program.

Code snippet for executing a query:

```
char const* const query =
    "DECLARE @iMM int, @sMM varchar(100); "
    "EXEC sp_myproc @sFoo = 'abcdef', @sBar = 'ghij', @iQux = 1,"
    "@iOutInt = @iMM output, @sOutString = @sMM output;"
    "PRINT @iMM; PRINT @sMM;";

auto result = SQLExecDirectA(handle, (SQLCHAR*)query, SQL_NTS);
```

This returns `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO` ., but `SQLGetDiagRecA` does not retrieve the printed output . `SQLMoreResults` returns `1`, `SQLParamData` returns `-1`.

The same query does execute successfully in SSMS but I can't figure out how to get the output parameter values programmatically.   There are various code examples using `SQLBindParameter` to retrieve multiple output parameters but none of them use named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the data this way (maybe not optimal but at least it works):

```
char const* const query =
    "EXEC sp_myproc @sFoo = 'abcdef', @sBar = 'ghij', @iQux = 1,"
    "@iOutInt = ? output, @sOutString = ? output;"

short out_int;
SQLBindParameter(handle, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_SSHORT, SQL_SMALLINT,
    0, 0, &out_int, 1, NULL);

char outbuf[61];
SQLBindParameter(handle, 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR,
    60, 0, outbuf, 60, NULL);

auto result = SQLExecDirectA(handle, (SQLCHAR*)query, SQL_NTS);

if ( result == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
{
     std::cout << out_int << ", '" << outbuf << "'\n";
}
```

Using SQL_CHAR instead of SQL_VARCHAR meant the result string was always right-padded with spaces .